# How to determine if my current position is inside a route

Tags: google-maps, routes, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to check if my current position is contained in my current route, so my code is getting my current position calling WatchPosition function and constantly verifying if my coordinates are between my origin and my destination coordinates:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(UpdatePosition);

function UpdatePosition(position){
  var currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
  var currentLon = position.coords.longitude;

  if(currentLat <= OriginLat && currentLon >= OriginLon && currentLat >= DestinationLat && currentLon <= DestinationLon){
     alert("Inside Current Route");
  }
  else{
     alert("Out Current Route");
  }
}
```

The problem is that my verification is not always valid, but i'm not sure why.

I'm using the following values:

```
OriginLat = -23.5833; OriginLon = -46.63689999999997.
DestinationLat = -23.6089009; DestinationLon = -47.02675499999998.
```

Anyone got any other suggestion to make this verification?

Comment: The reason your 'if' statement doesn't work is your route may not be oriented north-south or east-west.  You could either check your current position from the route line and if it is an acceptable error, then your are on path.  Another approach is use a point in polygon test.

Comment: Hey @TreyA, the point in polygon solved my problem.

Thank you very much!